# Comparing two strings in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Currently I am writing a batch file to accept a parameter and jump to a specific part of the file based on the parameter value. The code I have is as follows:

```
SET param = %~n1

IF "%param%"=="q" GOTO :QUICK
IF "%param%"=="t" GOTO :THOROUGH
IF "%param%"=="b" GOTO :BOOT
IF "%param%"=="f" GOTO :FIX
IF "%param%"=="" GOTO :INVALID


:QUICK
echo "Quick"
pause
exit

:INVALID
echo "Invalid"
pause
exit

:BOOT
echo "Boot"
pause
exit

:FIX
echo "Fix"
pause
exit

:THOROUGH
echo "Thorough"
pause
exit
```

The only parameters the script should accept are `/q, /t, /b or /f` (or without `/`), and when an incorrect parameter is supplied, it should jump to `INVALID`. When I run it with an invalid parameter, it works, however, if I supply a parameter that is correct (for example, `file.bat t`) the result fails to work as I hope, and ends up going directly to `INVALID`. I have tried using `"%param%" EQ "q"`, and setting `q` to a variable before doing the comparison, but I have had no luck coming up with a result that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have a parameter `%param%`. But you have a parameter named `%param<space>%` And it's value isn't `q`, but `<space>q`

Write your `set`command without spaces:

```
set param=%~n1
```

or even better (to avoid unintended spaces at the end):

```
set "param=%~n1"
```

Note: you can make your parameters case independent with `if /i "%param%"=="q"`

Comment: I didn't realize that the spaces between the variable and the equal sign were counted. It works perfectly now, thank you.