# How Assign values to variables if NULL in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am working on this python script which is to be executed using BAT file. 
The Batch file takes 3 parameters. If the user gives no parameters ( NULL ) while executing BAT file, the code should assign values to the 3 variables. ( repo_path, py_file_path, branch )

How does IF ELSE condition work in BAT? I tried `if %abc%=="" ( )` it did not work!! In fact the IF condition is failing.

Below is my code.

```
cls
set repo_path=%1
set py_file_path=%2
set branch=%3

IF [%repo_path%] == [] GOTO assign
:assign
set repo_path="C:\GIT\Analysis\360-analysis"
set py_file_path="C:\GIT\Analysis\360-analysis\NJ\WIP-Sai\Auto_Git_Project\Python_Files"
set branch="master"

echo %repo_path%
cd %repo_path%
python %py_file_path%\Auto_Git_Pull.py %branch%
pause
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two strings in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225563/comparing-two-strings-in-batch)

Comment: The expression `if %abc%==""` actually compares `string` with `"string"`...

Comment: For each individual variable within a script you would generally use this syntax, `If Not Defined repo_path set "repo_path=C:\GIT\Analysis\360-analysis"`. For the purposed of this exercise however, you could probably use `If "%~3" == "" GoTo …`

Comment: Instead of `==` you should use EQU, it might work. As for null values, there really isn't a specific null operator in batch. I would just create another variable with blank content and call it null. There is technically a null variable which is `nul` as used in `>nul` to silence outputs, but it cannot be used in comparisons like if.

Comment: Do not use `Equ`, because it is not designed for strings, you were correct in your use of `==`!. also `NUL` is not a variable it is a device.

Comment: @KenWhite i ran that as BAT file in Pycharm. it is almost working. It is NOT accepting blank ( null ) parameters though! but doesnt tell me how to exit the condition

Comment: @Compo thanks but seems like BAT reads line by line. It is passing if condition even if wrong also, how to exit the condition when completed.

Comment: Create a new empty file. Type in `echo %1`. On the next line, type `if "%1"=="" echo Empty`. Save the file as `stringtest.bat`. Run it from the command prompt as `stringtest 1`, and you'll see that it outputs `1` and nothing else. Run it again with `stringtest` and nothing else, and you'll see `ECHO is ON` followed by `Empty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example based upon my comment.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "repo_path=%~1"
Set "py_file_path=%~2"
Set "branch=%~3"

If Not Defined repo_path (
    Set "repo_path=C:\GIT\Analysis\360-analysis"
    Set "py_file_path=C:\GIT\Analysis\360-analysis\NJ\WIP-Sai\Auto_Git_Project\Python_Files"
    Set "branch=master"
)
Echo %repo_path%
CD /D "%repo_path%" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF
"F:\ullPath To\python.exe" "%py_file_path%\Auto_Git_Pull.py" "%branch%"
Pause
```

Please note, that in addition to the above example, you should really incorporate some methodology to check whether the input was only one or two arguments, or more than three, *(as opposed to just none or at least three)*. Also you should validate those entries, just in case the second argument was provided, but doesn't exist, and the same for the third argument. The example above will already close the script if the first argument isn't valid, *(using the code on line `12`)*.

Comment: CD /D "%repo_path%" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF what does this mean? Also I am closer than ever. I will test and respond. please hang on

Comment: @SaiAstro, change directory to the expanded value for the defined variable named `repo_path`, redirect any error from doing so to the `NUL` device, *(so that it isn't visible)*, and if the `CD` command is unsuccessful, i.e. the location doesn't exist, exit the script, _(`GoTo :EOF`)_.

Comment: you beautiful SOB! (sry but love u) i finally got it .. had to modify a bit but works! :)